# How to make swishy skirt without cloth sim?

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation

Im trying to make that moves like this one:[image]
I would use a cloth sim but my computer would explode if i used one.
I'm open to anything other than a cloth sim.
I've tried using a soft body sim but it doesn't look right.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What doesn't look right and which settings have you used for the softbody?  Quick test:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mBfX.gif It wobbles a little up and down at the beginning. Alternatively, a cloth sim with a very low-poly skirt and a mesh/surface deform modifier could work, maybe?

Comment: @Blunder when I do the softbody sim it just wobbles up and down instead of swishing. Could you share the settings you used?

Comment: there's an addon called Wiggle Bones that can make this kind of things, maybe try it? (Blunder's solution is the best though)

Comment: if you don't mind about interactivity (ie. move when the body moves, simulate physics and collisions), you could keyframe manually and add noise for similar effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example with a model to test the collision detection. The *Softbody* simulation requires a short "settle down" phase to move the mesh into place (30 to 50 frames). The skirt is a low-poly cylinder (448 verts), rotated faces and a *Bevel* modifier.

[image: animation of the skirt]

**Softbody settings for the skirt**

Created a vertex group named `Softbody` (or whatever you want to name it) and painted the weights in *Weight Paint* mode to adjust the strength of the goal. The Gradient brush works well for this. Make sure the top area has a weight of `1.0` to "pin" it.

[image: weight paint]

The settings for the *Softbody* physics are the following:

[image: softboy settings]

It's the *Goal > Vertex Group* = `Softbody` that you need to set, and

- *Goal > Settings > Stiffness* = `0.999`,
- *Goal > Settings > Damping* = `12.000`
- and *Goal > Strength > Default* = `0.850` that you need to increase.

And you might need to adjust **the *Collision Settings* for the body**:

[image: collision settings]

Increased the *Damping*, lowered *Thickness Outer* and *Inner*. Keep in mind, these values depend on the model size and can vary. The model here has real-world size.